# Redirect stdout and stderr in Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services, redirect

I created a windows service that can execute processes exposed via wcf (internal use only).  I recently ran into an issue where this works fine if I execute the process (cmd.exe) directly, but when installed to run as LOCALSYSTEM, output and error redirection didn't work.  After a day or so, I figured out that if I also redirect stdin, things work fine.  I found a related thread [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/4ce40b19-c442-4412-94b2-1ed24bdb9386), but no real resolution.

Anyway, I was wondering if anyone knows the reason for this and are there known issues with output in Windows Services?

One complication is that I recently installed W7 SP1, so I'm not sure if this changed the behavior or not since I haven't had a chance to uninstall and try again.

Answer (score 0):

The standard streams are only available to processes that are running interactively.  Windows Services do not run in interactive mode.

Comment: As I mentioned, I can fully access the streams when I redirect all 3.